# Why is MAP_GROWSDOWN mapping does not grow?

Tags: c, linux, mmap, segmentation-fault

I tried to create `MAP_GROWSDOWN` mapping with the expectation it would grow automatically. As specified in the manual page:

> MAP_GROWSDOWN
>
> This  flag  is used for stacks.  It indicates to the kernel virtual memory system that the mapping should extend downward in
>   memory.  The return address is one page lower than the memory area
>   that is actually created in the process's virtual address space. 
>   **Touching an address in the "guard" page below the mapping will cause**
>   **the mapping to grow by a page**. This growth can be repeated until the
>   mapping grows to within a page of the high end of the next lower
>   mapping, at which point touching the "guard" page will result in a
>   `SIGSEGV` signal.

So I wrote the following example to test the mapping growing:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *mapped_ptr = mmap(NULL, 4096,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK | MAP_GROWSDOWN,
                            -1, 0);
    if(mapped_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        int error_code = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot do MAP_FIXED mapping."
                        "Error code = %d, details = %s\n", error_code, strerror(error_code));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    volatile char *c_ptr_1 = mapped_ptr; //address returned by mmap
    *c_ptr_1 = 'a'; //fine

    volatile char *c_ptr_2 = mapped_ptr - 4095; //1 page below the guard
    *c_ptr_2 = 'b'; //crashes with SEGV
}
```

So I got `SEGV` instead of growing the mapping. What does it mean by growing here?

Comment: The `mapped_ptr` is already in the guard page. Touch it first before touching a page below it.

Comment: @ThomasJager Yeah. I tried to touch `mapped_ptr`. It was fined. But if I touch `mapped_ptr - 4095` after this it segfaults anyway (I expected it to grow further).

Comment: Please add the includes!

Comment: Hmm I run the code and I couldn't get it working. In fact as far as I could read, the MAP_GROWSDOWN is not used by anything anymore, not for stacks, and it doesn't really work and should be removed anyway. It does not have sufficient protection.

Comment: Please consider this: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0808.1/2846.html. Rather allocate a mapping big enough for the stack and *map* bottom of it from writes.

Comment: What's your kernel version?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I use `4.18.0-24-generic` Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Could you please elaborate a bit about the Patch you referred to? So allocating a guard page can overwrite the mapping of the another `mmap` call (I suspect the guard page mapping is done via `mmap` with flags `MAP_FIXED` and `PROT_NONE` protection). If so then it is clear what the patch author was talking about.

Comment: @St.Antario I am just linking that discussion because Drepper says that MAP_GROWSDOWN is fundamentally broken anyway. It isn't used on my machine for any processes either.

Comment: In any case on my machine there is only a <100KiB gap before the next mapping so it wouldn't probably work as you expected anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
volatile char *c_ptr_1 = mapped_ptr - 4096; //1 page below
```

With

```
volatile char *c_ptr_1 = mapped_ptr;
```

Because:

> **The return address is one page lower than the memory area that is actually created in the process's virtual address space.** Touching an address in the "guard" page below the mapping will cause the mapping to grow by a page.

Note that I tested the solution and it works as expected on kernel 4.15.0-45-generic.

Comment: did you test if this works? I couldn't get it to grow anyway, even if I successfully read `c_ptr_1[0]` and it returns 0 and I can set it, reads, writes to [-1] *will* sigsegv.

Comment: OK then kernel version might matter! 4.18.0-24-generic x86_64 Ubuntu here.

Comment: But did you try to map *more*?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Added a kernel version for you.

Comment: I had it fail on 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @ThomasJager I cannot confirm or deny your observations.

Comment: Can you explain why you removed `volatile`?

Comment: @St.Antario Added back. I compiled your code with no optimizations, so `volatile` wasn't necessary for me. But it works with `volatile` just as well.

Comment: @St.Antario please edit the question so that there are 2 accesses and the first access works and the second does not and then Maxim can verify it / Maxim: did you try accessing another page too?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Added the example when accessing 1 page below the guard fails.

Comment: @St.Antario `mapped_ptr - 4095` is not supposed to work at all. This is what my answer is trying to say.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin So there is only 1 guard page created on the `mmap` with `MAP_GROWSDOWN`. I thought as soon as we touch page that is right below the guard it should be reserved. There is _This growth can be repeated until the mapping grows to within a page of the high end of the next lower mapping_ part about repeating the grow...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and Maxim: Yeah the OP's updated code doesn't work for me. 
 And the returned pointer = the bottom of the mapping according to `/proc/PID/maps`, not one page below like the man page claims. 
 It's probably obsolete; `MAP_GROWSDOWN` might be broken or maybe finally removed in my 5.0.1 (Arch Linux) kernel.  https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/ (from 2008) says it's not usable, and should be deprecated.  The behaviour I see on Linux 5.0.1 is consistent with `MAP_GROWSDOWN` being silently ignored.  The man page saying "used for stacks" is a total joke; it isn't.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Update: I'm sure it's not fully removed from the kernel.  `/proc/PID/smaps` does show a `gd` flag.  But it may only work for mappings that start larger than 1 page?  The code in the question works for me after changing `4096` to `100*4096`.  And the `maps` entry does actually change to a lower start address but the same end address, so it is literally growing downward when I start with a 400k mapping.  https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4767 may be related.

Comment: But contrary to the man page, the `mmap` return value *was* the start address of the mapping in `maps`

Comment: @PeterCordes hmm that could be an explanation

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't want `MAP_GROWSDOWN`, and it's not how the main thread stack works.  [Analyzing memory mapping of a process with pmap. [stack]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893353/analyzing-memory-mapping-of-a-process-with-pmap-stack/56920770#56920770)  Nothing uses it, and pretty much nothing *should* use it.  The stuff in the man page saying it's "used for stacks" is wrong and should be fixed.

I suspect it might be buggy (because nothing uses it so usually nobody cares or even notices if it breaks.)

---

**Your code works for me if I change the `mmap` call to map more than 1 page.  Specifically, I tried `4096 * 100`.**  I'm running Linux 5.0.1 (Arch Linux) on bare metal (Skylake).

`/proc/PID/smaps` does show a `gd` flag.

And then (when single-stepping the asm) the `maps` entry does actually change to a lower start address but the same end address, so it is literally growing downward when I start with a 400k mapping.  This gives a 400k initial allocation *above* the return address, which grows to 404kiB when the program runs.  (The size for a `_GROWSDOWN` mapping is *not* the growth limit or anything like that.)

**https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4767 may be related;** something changed between kernel versions in CentOS 5.3 and 5.5.  And/or it had something to do with working in a VM (5.3) vs. not growing and faulting on bare metal (5.5).

---

I simplified the C to use `ptr[-4095]` etc:

```
int main(void){
    volatile char *ptr = mmap(NULL, 4096*100,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK | MAP_GROWSDOWN,
                            -1, 0);
    if(ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        int error_code = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot do MAP_FIXED mapping."
                        "Error code = %d, details = %s\n", error_code, strerror(error_code));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr[0] = 'a';      //address returned by mmap
    ptr[-4095] = 'b';  // grow by 1 page
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Og` gives asm that's nice-ish to single-step.

---

BTW, various rumours about the flag having been removed from glibc are obviously wrong.  This source does compile, and it's clear that it's also supported by the kernel, not silently ignored.  (Although the behaviour I see with size 4096 instead of 400kiB is exactly consistent with the flag being silently ignored.  However the `gd` VmFlag is still there in `smaps`, so it's not ignored at that stage.)

I checked and there was room for it to grow without coming close to another mapping.  So IDK why it didn't grow when the GD mapping was only 1 page.  I tried a couple times and it segfaulted each time.  With the larger initial mapping it never faulted.

Both times were with a store to the mmap return value (the first page of the mapping proper), then a store 4095 bytes below that.

Answer (score 8):

I know the OP has already accepted one of the answers, but unfortunately it does not explain why `MAP_GROWSDOWN` seems to work sometimes. Since this Stack Overflow question is one of the first hits in search engines, let me add my answer for others.

The documentation of `MAP_GROWSDOWN` needs updating. In particular:

> This growth can be repeated until the mapping grows to within a page
> of the high end of the next lower mapping, at which point touching the
> "guard" page will result in a SIGSEGV signal.

In reality, the kernel does not allow a `MAP_GROWSDOWN` mapping to grow closer than `stack_guard_gap` pages away from the preceding mapping. The default value is 256, but it can be overridden on the kernel command line. Since your code does not specify any desired address for the mapping, the kernel chooses one automatically, but is quite likely to end up within 256 pages from the end of an existing mapping.

**EDIT**:

Additionally, kernels before v5.0 deny access to an address which is more than 64k+256 bytes below stack pointer. See [this kernel commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1d8ca3be86ebc6a38dad8236f45c7a9c61681e78) for details.

This program works on x86 even with pre-5.0 kernels:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE   4096UL
#define GAP     512 * PAGE_SIZE

static void print_maps(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (f) {
        char buf[1024];
        size_t sz;
        while ( (sz = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, f)) > 0)
            fwrite(buf, 1, sz, stdout);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *p;
    void *stack_ptr;

    /* Choose an address well below the default process stack. */
    asm volatile ("mov  %%rsp,%[sp]"
        : [sp] "=g" (stack_ptr));
    stack_ptr -= (intptr_t)stack_ptr & (PAGE_SIZE - 1);
    stack_ptr -= GAP;
    printf("Ask for a page at %p\n", stack_ptr);
    p = mmap(stack_ptr, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
         MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_GROWSDOWN,
         -1, 0);
    printf("Mapped at %p\n", p);
    print_maps();
    getchar();

    /* One page is already mapped: stack pointer does not matter. */
    *p = 'A';
    printf("Set content of that page to \"%s\"\n", p);
    print_maps();
    getchar();

    /* Expand down by one page. */
    asm volatile (
        "mov  %%rsp,%[sp]"  "\n\t"
        "mov  %[ptr],%%rsp" "\n\t"
        "movb $'B',-1(%%rsp)"   "\n\t"
        "mov  %[sp],%%rsp"
        : [sp] "+&g" (stack_ptr)
        : [ptr] "g" (p)
        : "memory");
    printf("Set end of guard page to \"%s\"\n", p - 1);
    print_maps();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```